# Android: How-To create an app that pulls Album Art?

Tags: android, mp3, albumart, android-music-player

Where would I get started to create an app that would grab your Album Art based on Album or Artist of the mp3 from the internet (ie. via amazon, play.com, etc..)?

I would likely be using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Cusor cur = getContentResolver().query(Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {Albums.ALBUM_ART}, Albums._ID + "=?", new String[] {albumid}, null);
```

Album Artist is still undocumented and not available before 2.3.3, I believe.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know that about artist.  I have seen the [ArtistAlbumBrowserActivity.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/packages/apps/Music/src/com/android/music/ArtistAlbumBrowserActivity.java) but I couldn't make much of it nor with what exactly i'm trying to accomplish.